# Sikuli script stopping randomly

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I have a simple SikuliX script that I'm using to automate some simple testing tasks on a game. The script is just a infinite while loop that makes some clicks and drag/drop some stuff on the screen. It runs normally but sometimes, for no reason apparently, it stops running. Sometimes it runs for hours sometimes it lasts only 5 minutes. The whole code is just that:

```
def mandaMagia(magia):
    type(Key.ENTER)
    sleep(0.1) 
    type(magia)
    sleep(0.1) 
    type(Key.ENTER)
    sleep(0.1) 

def danca():
    type(Key.DOWN, Key.CTRL)
    sleep(0.2)
    type(Key.UP, Key.CTRL)
    sleep(0.1) 

def reloadStn():
    pos1 = Location(3136,260)
    pos2 = Location(3136,450)
    dragDrop(pos2, pos1)
    sleep(0.2)

def alimentarC1():
    rightClick(Location(3136,510))
    sleep(0.2)

def alimentarC2():
    rightClick(Location(2185,450))
    sleep(0.2)

def alimentarC3():
    rightClick(Location(1216,460))
    sleep(0.2)


def loopPrincipal():
    dancaCounter = 0
    while 1:
        try:
            alimentarC2()
            mandaMagia("s2")
            danca()
            alimentarC3()
            mandaMagia("s3")
            danca()
            alimentarC1()
            reloadStn()
            mandaMagia("s1")
            danca()
            sleep(0.3)
        except:
            print('Exception thrown')   

loopPrincipal()
print('script end')
```

When the script stops, I check the sikulx IDE to see it there is any exception thrown but there isn't. I also check in the terminal, since I run it with the command `java -jar sikulixide-2.0.4.jar` but also see no error message. What can be wrong here? Why doesn't the loop just run indefinitely? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** So I've put these two print messages, one in the except block and other after the loop end and noticed that when the error happens none of these messages are printed, I still have no idea what else to do to find out what's happening. I noticed that most (but not all) the times that it happens is just afther running the `type(Key.DOWN, Key.CTRL)`/`type(Key.UP, Key.CTRL)` commands.

Comment: Do a proper investigation and try to figure out when it stops. Look at the logs and try to see whether it stops at the same point. Add printouts after every single step and see where your script stops running.

Comment: In the logs it looks like it always stops (or before?) after using the keyboard. I placed a `print` command in the `except` but it also doesn't print anything.

Comment: Same thing happening with me